# Merge 2 images on windows phone 8.1 (WinRT/Universal)

Tags: windows, image, merge, windows-runtime, universal

Is there a simple way to merge 2 .PNG files into another .PNG file, using code behind?
I've searched the web and found some examples but they tend to be too complex and not fully compatible.
I'd like to load "Assets/src1.png", "Assets/src2.png" and merge them into a temporary file so I can use in a tile.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you want them merged? By alpha & overlaying? Could you do it with an external program (e.g. paint.net) and then import that asset?

Comment: I could, but that would mean increasing my app size a LOT. I prefer to do it at runtime. It's like merging a photo with a frame, I don't really care how it's done, as long as I can use it in a tile :)

Comment: perhaps try setting the background colour to transparent, and just overlaying the images? i.e. make the images ~100 alpha to begin with and then have 2 picture elements

Comment: And then could I use it in a tile? I'm trying to do it with Lumia Imaging SDK but I'm also stuck on converting a BitmapImage into an IBuffer.